# Analog scope has infinite resolution (vertical)?

Tags: analog, oscilloscope

An old dude told me that I should go for analog ones since those digital even 14bit ones couldn't resolute as well as the old class scopes, aka. analog scopes. Is this true....

Comment: Next time a "dude" tells you something, ask them to **elaborate** on that. That usually shuts up these "dudes" as it is often just **their own misconception** of how things work. So say: **OK, now prove it**. I can prove the "Dude" is **WRONG** and so can you after watching Dave from EEVBlog explaining how things do work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Znwp0pK8Tzk  Sure the video is about noise but that is what limits the resolution so it still applies.

Comment: With the 8-10 bit ones there's an element of truth in it, but by the time you get to 14 bit... what does 1 LSB equate to in vertical step size? In the region of 10 microns... where the analog scope really scores is in never aliasing, I've seen some odd and misleading artefacts on DSOs.

Comment: Yeah, ask your old dude to calculate the [ENOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_number_of_bits) of that scope, he might be surprised.

Comment: Well nothing wrong with having an analog scope sitting around but don't pay much more than 1-2 $/MHz bandwidth

Answer (score 4):

In an ideal world, where your oscilloscope doesn't introduce any noise, and it produces a zero-width line on the screen (and let's suppose you're able to see it then!) and assuming that your coating is an infinite set of points, yes.

But, the answer is **no**, because your scope is made of real components, which will add noise (which adds to the signal's noise), and the beam width is finite (and while its center-line position might be thought as continuous, you still must face with the phosphor coating of the screen, which is at the end a discrete array of molecules. Still this would be the the very upper limit, assuming a **very** sharp line and no noise).

"14-bit resolution" means 16384 levels. Assume you have a nice screen scope, 16-cm high. Can you spot 10 um of difference?

Answer (score 2):

If the dude has eagle eyes and photo memory,... the old analog scope can't compete with a DSO in terms of functionality, not sure if he can take an advantage of signal looking at phosphorus glowing screen rather than on LCD.

Comment: I imagine the width and persistence of the phosphorus line add an effective limit on the resolution.

Comment: @TomCarpenter Indeed, and there was a huge variation between analog scopes in line width. My old Hameg 605 focuses much more sharply (and so resolves better) than any Tektronik scope I have ever seen (though I have a Tek245B for speed)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a scope (analog or digital) with a very low input noise like \$ 1nV/ \sqrt{Hz} \$ ...

Getting 1nV/rtHz on 1MegOhm input resistance is not a "stick an opamp in and be done with it" job, most likely you're looking at 5-10 matched low noise JFETs in parallel, aaand... we just lost the 10pF input capacitance spec...

Low noise requires low impedances, and big transistors, thus high capacitance. "Low noise and slow" is no problem. "Low noise and high speed" tends to involve exotic RF parts, 50R impedances, and money.

Also you have the input attenuator problem. If you connect the input coax straight into the input amp, then your maximum sensitivity setting is going to be quite low-noise, however it will tend to burn when probing voltages that are a bit too high. So, add some input protection circuits, and...

Yeah, about that attenuator, obviously it should be before the input amp to make sure it doesn't clip, but that increases noise when attenuating, so here, have a bunch of RF relays at 20 bucks a pop to make the optimum combination between attenuating before or after the input amp, maybe use a variable gain chip, etc.

That's why all scopes below say, $1000, have tons of noise, although some suck a lot more than others. Analog or digital, it's all in the input amp and attenuator, and it all comes down to money.

So, a scope with \$ 5nV/ \sqrt{Hz} \$ and 200MHz bandwidth will have 70µV noise. Analog or digital.

Now if we have a 8-bit ADC we'll tune the full scale amplitude so that this noise corresponds to half a LSB. So, the vertical range on our screen would be 9mV, let's say 1mV/div.

Most analog or digital scopes on 1mV/div already have quite a bit of fuzz on the trace.

So, duuuuuude, if you want less noise, you have options:

- Magic button #1: "Bandwidth limit" if the signal allows it.
- Magic button #2: "Set averaging to 1024 traces" if the signal is periodic, in which case the digital scope utterly destroys the analog one:

[image]

- Export a few thousand periods on a USB key, load it up in python, average and plot (when I'm frustrated that the scope doesn't let me zoom into the averaged waveform, there is signal inside those pixels!).
- If the signal is low frequency, make a simple preamp+lowpass filter with an opamp. By virtue of having a lower bandwidth, it will have lower noise in the first place, and you can use lower noise parts like an ADA4898-1... or just use a soundcard.
- Or buy a much more expensive 12 bit scope, which is the only way if your signal is non-repetitive (no averaging) and fast (no bandwidth limit button). But if the signal is non-repetitive, then the analog scope is useless also.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the short answer.

Technically an analog oscilloscope has infinite vertical resolution because it is driving by analog deflector plates instead of an ADC with quantized levels.

**But** you also have to consider the oscilloscope's noise floor. Both analog and digital oscilloscopes will have some level of baseline noise that will drown out the vertical resolution. That's why an 8 bit oscilloscope usually offers plenty of vertical resolution.

Answer (score 0):

TEK 556 dual-beam has 500 micron spot size (been years since I used it). You can measure RC taus with only 1 division deflection.

My favorite plugin, for TEK7904, is the 7A22 plugin with 10uV/division floor, selectable bandwidths from 1KHz to 1MHz upper corner, and a number of DC-blocking high-pass corners for the lower corner. Using this to examine magnetic field coupling thru copper foil, to learn the limits of magnetic shielding.